# What are the original tires for the 2002 Honda Accord SE? Any place for me to check?

Tags: honda, tires, accord

For example, the brand and size. Is there any place for me to check what the original tires which come with the car are? I live in Canada and whenever I search it on Google the links lead to goodyear.ca where I can search for available tires.

Comment: Do your search in an incognito window. The tire size was P195/65R15, but what is the reason you need to be specific about the OEM brand? A cursory search for the brand yielded nothing for me as to what the brand would be.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks for the info. I search in a regular window. I'm looking for tires with the same 'specs' (I'm not a car guy. I basically want tires of the similar size, diameter, rim etc.. whatever is important). I want to replace my tires and don't know what I am supposed to look for so I decided I should just get Michelin tires (the only brand I'm familiar with) which are the most similar to the original tires, which is why I wanted the details of the original tires.

Comment: You can go to any major tire site and get plenty of different tire suggestions. Ones like [TireRack.com](http://www.tirerack.com/content/tirerack/desktop/en/homepage.html) or [DiscountTireDirect.com](http://www.discounttiredirect.com/direct/home.do). There are plenty of others.

Answer (score 5):

All cars have a tire information sticker somewhere in the driver door jam. The sticker will list the tire size and speed rating. The exact brand is not important and can't be easily traced either. I worked at a dealership for a few years and it was not uncommon for a single model of cars to come with three different tires on it. Choose the tire based on the driving that you do and the conditions that the tire will see.

Comment: And don't forget to look at customer feedback on any model of tire you are looking at. If there is a systemic problem with a tire, it will show up over and over again there. Don't trust outliers, as you will always get people who really love or really hate a tire, but it really doesn't reflect the true nature of the tire itself.